# PHP DOMDocument Writing Sitemap Problems - Uncaught exception 'DOMException'

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I keep getting the following error when I add xmlns to my xml written with DOMDocument

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Invalid Character Error' in...

```
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml_urlset = $xml->createElement('urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"');
$xml_url = $xml->createElement("url","this text");
$xml_urlset->appendChild($xml_url);
$xml->appendChild($xml_urlset);
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->save("test.xml");
```

Also, even though I have formatOutput =  true I still get everything written out as one long line:

```
<urlset>xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"<url>this text</url></urlset>
```

I was trying to set things so this could be outputed for the urlset

```
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
```

**Thank you for any help you can give me.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `createElement` is completely bogus.  You can't add attributes that way.  Try this:

```
<?php
$xml = new DOMDocument("1.0", "UTF-8");
$xml_urlset = $xml->createElement('urlset');
$xml_urlset->setAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
$xml_urlset->setAttribute('xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$xml_urlset->setAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
$xml_url = $xml->createElement("url","this text");
$xml_urlset->appendChild($xml_url);
$xml->appendChild($xml_urlset);
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->save("test.xml");
?>
```